# How can I get three lines of data to show on a single line?

Tags: join, left-join, inner-join, union

as you can see from the image I am returning the top example of data, what i would like to do is stretch it across a single line. So instead of showing each Job on a separate line I would like to show all three jobs across the same line(see the example in the pic) so starting with staff number, location, name and then Job1 number, Job1 name, Job1 hours  -  followed by Job2 number, Job2 name, Job2 hours   -  followed by Job3 number, Job3 name, Job 3 hours.

**the top example in the pic is what i am getting and the bottom example is what i would like to do.**

Is this possible? your help will be very much appreciated, Thank you in advance.

[image]

the code i am using is:

```
select  
viewCarerContractFull.CarerCode 
, viewTeam.description as Location
, viewCarerContractFull.surname
, isnull (tblCarerContract.PayrollNumber, 0) as JobNumber
, viewCarerContractFull.ContractName as JobName
, ISNULL(DateDiff (hour,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000',tblCarerContract.Contracthours),0)          ContractHours

from viewCarerContractFull 
join tblCarerContract on tblCarerContract.CarerContractCode = viewCarerContractFull.CarerContractCode
join viewTeam as viewTeam on viewTeam.TeamCode = tblCarerContract.TeamCode

where 
viewCarerContractFull.LeaveDate IS NULL 

Group by 
viewCarerContractFull.CarerCode 
, viewTeam.description
, viewCarerContractFull.surname
, tblCarerContract.PayrollNumber
, viewCarerContractFull.ContractName 
, tblCarerContract.Contracthours
```

Comment: What platform are you using? (SQL Server, Oracle, MYSQL, etc.) Also, include the code that you've got so far.

Comment: Looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820972/t-sql-joining-result-sets-horizontally

Comment: There are several examples on the site. Search for a self-join.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I am using SQL Server and here is the code above

Comment: Search here for `SQL Pivot` and include the name of the DBMS you're using, like `MySQL SQL Pivot` or 'Sql Server SQL Pivot`. There are dozens of previous questions and answers here for various DBMSes.

Comment: Another possible search phrase: `SQL columns to rows`

Comment: Thank you for your comments, much appreciated.  I have been able to do it by creating multiple subqueries, one for name etc and one subquery for each job and filtered it to a job number, then joined each job to the basic subquery to add the job columns in. Thank you to all